# Display positive result with a plus sign (+) in SQL

Tags: sql, formatting, number-formatting

I have the following query:

```
    SELECT 
      CONVERT(DECIMAL(11,1),SUM(Column/1000*-1)) AS NAME,
    FROM
      Table
```

The reason i have "/1000*-1" is that I would like the results to be displayed in units of thousands and inverted (negative values as positive and vice versa) with only one decimal place.

How can I get the positive values have a plus sign (+) in front of them just like the negative values have a dash sign (-) ?

Comment: It is the presentation layer that should be dealing with the output format. SQL queries only provide you with data.

Comment: As an aside, you could also invert the sign of the result like this: `-Column` (instead of `Column`), or like this: `Column/-1000` or like this: `-SUM(Column/1000)` or even like this: `-CONVERT(DECIMAL(11,1),SUM(Column/1000))`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  case 
     when CONVERT(DECIMAL(11,1),SUM(Column/1000*-1)) >= 0 
     then concat('+', CONVERT(DECIMAL(11,1),SUM(Column/1000*-1))) 
     else CONVERT(DECIMAL(11,1),SUM(Column/1000*-1)) 
  end AS NAME
FROM Table
```

Comment: You should probably replace `>= 0` with `> 0`. (You don't want `+0.0` in the output, do you?)

Comment: and he don't want -0.0 too :D

Comment: One other thing is, you seem to be implying that a number will be implicitly converted to a string and not the other way around. Since we know nothing about the OP's database system at the moment, we shouldn't rely on implicit conversion rules *we* have been used to.

Comment: @FahimParkar: This solution isn't trying to stick `-` in front of a non-positive value, so `0.0` or a negative value would be returned as is.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. I get the following error "'concat' is not a recognized function name." Using SQL Query Analyzer version 8.0.

Comment: @user1423223: what DB engine are you using?

Comment: @user1423223: then try `'+' + cast(CONVERT(DECIMAL(11,1),SUM(Column/1000*-1)) as char(50))` instead of `concat('+', CONVERT(DECIMAL(11,1),SUM(Column/1000*-1)))`

Comment: @juergend: You would need to cast the `ELSE` term as a string as well.

Comment: Thank you all, that worked! I used:                                               case
 when CONVERT(DECIMAL(11,1),SUM(Column/1000*-1)) > 0
 then '+' + cast(CONVERT(DECIMAL(11,1),SUM(Column/1000*-1)) as char(50))
 else cast(CONVERT(DECIMAL(11,1),SUM(Column/1000*-1)) as char(50))
 end AS Name,

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-formatting.html   Table 9-26. Template Patterns for Numeric Formatting   SG plus/minus sign in specified position

Answer (score 9):

You can use **semicolon-separated** multi-part strings with the **`FORMAT`** function (kind of like you would with custom number formats in Microsoft Excel).

> A number format can have up to **three sections** of formatting code, separated by **semicolons**. These code sections define the format for positive numbers, negative numbers, and zero values, in that order:
>
> ### `<POSITIVE>;<NEGATIVE>;<ZERO>`
>
> **example:**
>
> ### **`FORMAT(@YourValue,'+0.0;-0.0')`**
>
> <sup>(Adapted from [**this**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-or-delete-a-custom-number-format-78f2a361-936b-4c03-8772-09fab54be7f4#bm1))</sup>

---

I usually also *hide zeros* when displaying `+/-` signs so I use formatting string: **`'+0;-0;'''`**

`SELECT FORMAT(+5,'+0;-0;''')  --returns:` **`+5`**
`SELECT FORMAT(-5,'+0;-0;''')  --returns:` **`-5`**
`SELECT FORMAT(-5,'+0;-0;''')  --returns:` ***`<empty string>`***

---

To display zero's as well you could use formatting string: **`'+0;-0;0'`**

---

Applies to: [tsql](/questions/tagged/tsql), [azure-sql-database](/questions/tagged/azure-sql-database), [sql-server-2012](/questions/tagged/sql-server-2012), [sql-server-2014](/questions/tagged/sql-server-2014), [sql-server-2016](/questions/tagged/sql-server-2016)

---

### More Information:

- Microsoft Docs : [**`FORMAT`** (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
- Microsoft Docs : [**Formatting Types**](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/formatting-types)
  <sup>(Doc is for [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) but also applies to the `FORMAT` function)</sup>
- Microsoft Docs : [**`SIGN`** (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sign-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 1):

In MYSQL, this works ...

CONCAT(IF(TimeZone>0,'+',''),TimeZone)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  REPLACE(CONCAT('+', CONVERT(DECIMAL(11,1),SUM(Column/1000*-1))), '+-', '-')
FROM
  Table
```

This approach will show `+0.0`, though.

Answer (score 0):

I might have a quick fix to propose.

**My problematic :**

> Send an automatic weekly report about the business performance. Display for the variations rates their positive / negative sign in order to improve readability.

**In SQL :**

```
IF(var_wow < 0, CAST(var_wow AS STRING), CONCAT('+', var_wow)) AS var_wow
```

Hope it will help !

Best,