# Oracle TO_CHAR Format Module 'FM099999999V99MI' equivalent in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, currency, to-char, format-model

I am moving data from Oracle to an MS SQL server. I'm using a `TO_CHAR` Format module for the amount field to change the amount to the desired format using FM. I'm looking for an equivalent function in the SQL server to get the same output.

Oracle:

```sql
Select Amount, TO_CHAR(Amount, 'FM099999999V99MI') as Converted from Billing_table
```

Output:

| Amount | Converted |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 00000000000 |
| 1985.56 | 00000198556 |
| 18.63 | 00000001863 ​ |
| -258.93 | 00000025893- ​ |
| -6.02 | 00000000602- ​ |

Comment: You want the negative sign on the right? Must be some industry-specific thing I will never understand even if you explain it to me (so don't bother) but that's quite odd to say the least.

Comment: yeah I'm on the same boat as you are! that's how the requirement from the vendor :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795990/display-positive-result-with-a-plus-sign-in-sql) and [custom format string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings) you may use:

> ```
> with a as (
>   select *
>   from(values (0), (1985.56), (18.63), (-258.93), (-6.0234), (-10)) as t(val)
> )
> select
>   val,
>   /*Set explicit format with fixed decimal points*/
>   replace(format(val, '000000000.00;000000000.00-'), '.', '') as formatted,
>   /*Explicit multiplication*/
>   format(val*100, '00000000000;00000000000-') as formatted2
> from a
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
>       val | formatted    | formatted2  
> --------: | :----------- | :-----------
>    0.0000 | 00000000000  | 00000000000 
> 1985.5600 | 00000198556  | 00000198556 
>   18.6300 | 00000001863  | 00000001863 
> -258.9300 | 00000025893- | 00000025893-
>   -6.0234 | 00000000602- | 00000000602-
>  -10.0000 | 00000001000- | 00000001000-
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=daed127f58fbe0b45903e7138032c403)*

Answer (score 4):

SQL Server does have `format()`, but be warned.  It should be used **sparingly** due to  performance issues.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (Amount*100 decimal(15,2))
Insert Into @YourTable values
 (0)
,(1985.56)
,(18.63)
,(-258.93)
,(-6.02)


Select Amount 
      ,Converted =  format(Amount*100,'00000000000;00000000000-')
 From  @YourTable
```

**Results**

```
Amount  Converted
0.00    00000000000
1985.56 00000198556
18.63   00000001863
-258.93 00000025893-
-6.02   00000000602-
```

Answer (score 3):

There are probably 100 different ways to do this. `FORMAT()` definitely seems cleaner and more intuitive but like John I stay away from it [due to performance overhead](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but).

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.nums(val decimal(15,2));

INSERT dbo.nums(val) VALUES(0),
(1985.56),
(18.63),
(-258.93),
(-6.02);

SELECT val, RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',11) 
    + RTRIM(CONVERT(int,100*ABS(val))),11) 
    + CASE WHEN val < 0 THEN '-' ELSE '' END
  FROM dbo.nums;
```

Results:

| val | (No column name) |
| --- | --- |
| 0.00 | 00000000000 |
| 1985.56 | 00000198556 |
| 18.63 | 00000001863 |
| -258.93 | 00000025893- |
| -6.02 | 00000000602- |

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f92e62a36037360ff53498fa9542a8e0)

Comment: Full Disclosure:  I'll use format() from time to time, but only on SMALL sets.   Some believe format() is evil while I see it as just another option ... another tool in the belt.  Either way +1 for the more performant option.

Comment: @John yes I think format() is handy in a pinch but like you say at scale it can be a killer, and you’re usually better off doing that kind of presentation-layer stuff at the presentation layer if it’s even moderately complex anyway. I’m a very “don’t use exceptions even if you fully understand why the exception is ok in this case and the dangers of using it in other cases” - if the exception needs a disclaimer and its own documentation… :-)

Comment: Thank John Cappelletti it worked as I expected appreciate your quick response. Thanks Everyone